# [Python][Tornado]: 500 Internal Server Error when navigating between pages

Tags: html, python-3.x, tornado

I'm trying to navigate between 2 HTML pages through Tornado. Following is the code for the routes and their respective handlers:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        log.info("Rendering index.html")
        self.render("index.html")

class NotificationsPageHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        log.info("Rendering notifications")
        self.render("notifications.html")

def start_server():

    settings = {
        "static_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static")
    }

    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler), 
        (r"/notifications.html", NotificationsPageHandler),
    ], **settings)

    application.listen(8989)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

When I load 127.0.0.1:8989 on the browser, I get the index.html page but when I try to navigate to notifications.html through an anchor tag in index.html, I get the following stack trace:

```
2016-07-06 12:07:06,546 - tornado.application - ERROR - Uncaught exception GET /notifications.html (127.0.0.1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='127.0.0.1:8989', method='GET', uri='/notifications.html', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', headers={'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 'Host': '127.0.0.1:8989', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36', 'Referer': 'http://127.0.0.1:8989/', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1443, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
  File "BADWebServer.py", line 231, in get
    self.render("notifications.html")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 699, in render
    html = self.render_string(template_name, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 806, in render_string
    return t.generate(**namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado/template.py", line 345, in generate
    return execute()
  File "notifications_html.generated.py", line 5, in _tt_execute
    _tt_tmp = item.score  # notifications.html:37
NameError: name 'item' is not defined
2016-07-06 12:07:06,548 - tornado.access - ERROR - 500 GET /notifications.html (127.0.0.1) 4.51ms
```

I have seen a similar post, [how to navigate from one html to other in tornado using anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34575989/how-to-navigate-from-one-html-to-other-in-tornado-using-anchor-tag) but I'm not sure why I'm getting the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because, as the trace says, "name 'item' is not defined". Your notifications.html template contains some markup like:

```
{{ item.score }}
```

... but you haven't passed an "item" variable in. [See the template syntax guide for an example](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/templates.html#template-syntax).

Comment: Yes, that is true. But I was expecting the Tornado web server to just give back the HTML to the client rather than parse through it. I guess my understanding of how the web server works is wrong! From the link that you have shared, it seems that Tornado can also do some computation on the HTML. The HTML file had the {{ item.score }} for use with Angular on the client side. Any suggestion how I can prevent Tornado from parsing the HTML and blindly return it?

Comment: If you don't want to use Tornado template rendering, return the contents with StaticFileHandler instead  RequestHandler.